# Turn on or off all mail flowrules using powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2013, exchange-management-shell

I have 128 MailFlow rules within an exchange 2013 server. I am looking for a way to turn on or turn off all the rules with a powershell script.

I know that I can use

```
Disable-TransportRule "RuleName"
```

to turn off a rule.

My problem is trying to incorporate that in to a loop with powershell. I just don't have the knowledge of the powershell language.
I've read up about loops and tried using variations on:

```
$rule = Get-TransportRule
Foreach($r in $rule)
{Disable-TransportRule $r.indentity}
```

However the loop fails with 2 or 3 errors.
Can anyone help or does anyone have any decent links to Powershell tutorials so that I can self-learn powershell loops and coding.

Comment: You misspelled the `Identity` property. Use `Disable-TransportRule $r.Identity`

Comment: I still get the following error: Disable-TransportRule : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Indentity' becuase it is null.

Comment: Found the problem. Within the TransportRule the field is Name, not Indentity.